# unable to save datatable while loop

Tags: asp.net

```
  when trying to save data in loop its skip 1 row.

    date      ins_amt  paid  mrno       paid status
1 09-Dec-16   16800   16800   11  NULL    1
2 09-Jan-17   16800   16800   11  NULL    1
3 09-Feb-17   17220   17220   11  NULL    1
4 09-Mar-17   17220   0       NULL    `enter code here`
5 26-Feb-17   17220   30      NULL    

i want my data should save like this:-

    date      ins_amt  paid    mrno       paid status
1   09-Dec-16   16800   16800   11  NULL    1
2   09-Jan-17   16800   16800   11  NULL    1
3   09-Feb-17   17220   17220   11  NULL    1
4   09-Mar-17   17220   30      NULL    
5   26-Feb-17   17220   0       NULL
```

suppose i want to save  50850 in paid amt. first it should check ins_amt     if     ins_amt > 50850 then 1st row paid amt should be 16800 then 50850-16800     rest should be next row until it meet criteria if ins_amt < given amt the   should be in next row.
but in my code last balance skip 1 rows.

```
       Int64 third = ((Convert.ToInt64(instamt.Text)));// eg:- 50850
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select pflno,pfname,insno,insdate,insamt,lastpaid from repaysec where pflno = '" + Label1.Text + "'and (paid = '' or paid is null) order by cast([insdate] as datetime) asc", con);
        dt21.Clear();
        adapt.Fill(dt21);
        con.Close();
        DataTable table = dt21;
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) // Loop over the rows.
        {
        Int64.Parse(row[4].ToString());

        Int64 first = Int64.Parse(row[4].ToString());
        Int64 second = Int64.Parse(row[5].ToString());

        third = second + third;

        if (first < third)
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update repaysec set lastpaid=@lastpaid,paid=@paid,mrno=@mrno where pflno=@pflno and insno=@insno and insdate=@insdate", con);
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pflno", Label1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@insno", row[2].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@insdate", row[3].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastpaid", first);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mrno", ct.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paid", "1");
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                third = third - first;
                third = second + third;
            }

        }


        else if (first > third)
        {


                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update repaysec set lastpaid=@lastpaid,paid=@paid where pflno=@pflno and insno=@insno and insdate=@insdate", con);
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pflno", Label1.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@insno", row[2].ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@insdate", row[3].ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastpaid", third);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paid", "");
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    third = 0;
                }
                break;

        }
        else if (first == third)
        {
            third = second + third;
             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update repaysec set  lastpaid=@lastpaid,paid=@paid,mrno=@mrno where pflno=@pflno and insno=@insno     and insdate=@insdate", con);
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pflno", Label1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@insno", row[2].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@insdate", row[3].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastpaid", third);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mrno", ct.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paid", "1");
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                third = 0;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: chke next comments

Comment: *Instead* of pulling the data to the client only to send it back to the server, write *only* three `UPDATE FROM WHERE` statements with the filters you want. This will result in almost N times faster execution, where N the number of rows. Instead of executing 1 select and N updates, you execute only 3 updates and avoid all data transfer. In fact, if N is large, the network overhead will be so large that you may get multiples of N in performance improvement

Comment: PS - your select is susceptible to dependency injection. Use a parameterized query there as well

Comment: please send some example of parameterized query